# how can i extract the colors in the image using java?

Tags: java, ocr, rgb, bufferedimage

I am trying with the following code to extract the colors in an image. I am using the following code but it is unable fetch the colors. Can anyone have better solution or please tell what is wrong in my code.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    File file = new File("image.png");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
    //  int clr;
    int redd = 0;
    int greenn = 0;
    int bluee = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < image.getHeight(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < image.getWidth(); j++) {
            int clr = image.getRGB(i, j);
            redd = (clr & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            greenn = (clr & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            bluee = clr & 0x000000ff;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Red Color value = " + redd);
    System.out.println("Green Color value = " + greenn);
    System.out.println("Blue Color value = " + bluee);
```

Any suggestions will be highly helpful, Thanks :-)

Comment: You want the color from where exactly because you read ALL the image BUT you overwrite at each iteration so you will have only the data of the last pixel

Comment: The width and height of the image are swapped. Apart from that, the code is basically "correct", so it's not clear what the actual question is. (If the problem is an exception, you should at least have mentioned it)

Answer (score 0):

You might better off using Java's [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) library to parse the image's RGB components:

```
Color clr = new Color(image.getRGB());
redd = c.getRed();
greenn = c.getGreen();
bluee = c.getBlue();
```

Can you see if that helps?

Comment: i have tried with this code but its now working, in getrgb it asking for coordinates,if i assign coordinates it throws same error as i asked in question

Comment: Can you update your post with what errors are being thrown?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `javafx features` :

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.PixelReader;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Image image = new Image("image.png");
        PixelReader reader = image.getPixelReader();
        Color c = reader.getColor(154, 87);
        System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which ? Have you changed the path to the image .. ?

Comment: yes i have changed the path to image, but it is throwing lot of errors

Comment: neither in your post nor in nowhere you post the errors .. please give them